# How to calculate the closeness between two curves

Tags: graphics

In engineering practice, it is often necessary to evaluate how close a curve is to the standard curve to evaluate the roughness parameter corresponding to the object.

[image]

[image]

I want to know which built-in functions can fulfill such requirements.

Comment: There are loads of ways to do this. Which one do you prefer? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_roughness . You could integrate the squared difference between the curves and get an RMS value.

Comment: The [Distance and Similarity Measures](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DistanceAndSimilarityMeasures.html) documentation page has a summary of related functions.